# Spring Actuator /Health Logger set to OFF, yet still logging

Tags: spring-boot, logging, spring-boot-actuator

I want to set the Logger for just the /health actuator endpoint to OFF in the application.properties file. Application is on Spring Boot 1.5. 
The /health would be our new monitoring url for the F5. I don't want to flood the logs. 
I have this.

```
    logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG

    org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Logger=OFF
    logging.level.org.springframework.boot.actuate.health=OFF
```

I'm still getting DEBUG logging in the console and the log file. The only thing that works is setting the first one to INFO or higher. But, that is not desirable. So, right now i'm getting this

```
2020-05-06 17:14:01.545 DEBUG 58588 --- [nio-9095-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/health]
2020-05-06 17:14:01.552 DEBUG 58588 --- [nio-9095-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/health] is: -1
2020-05-06 17:14:01.848 DEBUG 58588 --- [nio-9095-exec-5] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Written [UP {}] as "application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@144409aa]
2020-05-06 17:14:01.849 DEBUG 58588 --- [nio-9095-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2020-05-06 17:14:01.849 DEBUG 58588 --- [nio-9095-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

Do i need to set a different logger property? For a different class/package?

Comment: Well with that config I would expect to see that output I would think. Which lines of the output are you trying to turn off ?4 are from the DispactcherServlet, and you have org.springframework.web set to DEBUG, the other is the RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor, which is also in org.springframework.web

Comment: @JamesGawron Thanks for response. Correct. My understanding was that turning Logging OFF from the actuator framework for /health would prevent any logging from hitting it, including DispatcherServlet, and RequestResponseBodyMethod.  Yes, turning 'logging.level.org.springframework' to other than DEBUG would prevent it, but that'd prevent all other DEBUGS, don't want that. '/health' was going to be used from the f5 as a monitoring, hitting every 15-20 seconds, so prefer not to have these outputs flood the logs, if possible. Maybe I'm going about this wrong.

Comment: Have you found a workaround for this? I'm also interested in achieving this.

Comment: I am looking for the same. Has anyone figured out a way?

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Has anyone figured out a way?

Answer (score 5):

I use logback, so I added a logging filter for this. You need to change the regexes to match your own logging format.

```java
package eu.stackoverflow.logging;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.core.filter.Filter;
import ch.qos.logback.core.spi.FilterReply;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class IgnoringHealthAndPrometheusLoggingFilter extends Filter<ILoggingEvent> {

    private static final Pattern HEALTH_OR_PROMETHEUS =
        Pattern.compile("GET \"/(health|prometheus)\", parameters=\\{}");
    private static final Pattern COMPLETED =
        Pattern.compile("Completed 200 OK");

    private Set<String> activeThreads = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public FilterReply decide(ILoggingEvent loggingEvent) {
        if (isHealthOrPrometheus(loggingEvent.getMessage())) {
            activeThreads.add(loggingEvent.getThreadName());
            return FilterReply.DENY;
        } else if (isCompleted200Ok(loggingEvent.getMessage()) && activeThreads.remove(loggingEvent.getThreadName())) {
            return FilterReply.DENY;
        } else {
            return FilterReply.ACCEPT;
        }
    }

    private boolean isHealthOrPrometheus(String message) {
        return HEALTH_OR_PROMETHEUS.matcher(message).matches();
    }

    private boolean isCompleted200Ok(String message) {
        return COMPLETED.matcher(message).matches();
    }
}
```

```xml
    <appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender" name="CONSOLE">
        <filter class="eu.stackoverflow.logging.IgnoringHealthAndPrometheusLoggingFilter" />
    </appender>
```

More info on logback filters: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html